# Is there a way to reference a javascript array directly without assigning it to a var?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to do something like this to generate some text blocks with a little variety:

```js
["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"][Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]
```

Is it possible to reference the `length` property without first saving the array as a var? I'd like to do this in a one line so it's simpler to put this into string literals with minimal extra steps.

Comment: `["a", "b", "c"].length` ??

Comment: No. It’s all part of the same expression

Comment: You're not going to get `this` assigned the way your code asks, so no. Assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reference an array in two places without *literally* assigning it to a variable in *at least some* way.
There is an easy way to get a random item without any variables tho

```
["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)[0]
```

as `.sort()` sorts depending on if result is positive or negative, and `Math.random() - 0.5` is equally randomly positive or negative

---

Ways with variable

```
function rndItem(HERE) { return HERE[Math.floor(Math.random() * HERE.length)] }
rndItem(["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
/* --- --- --- */
[["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]].map(HERE => HERE[Math.floor(Math.random() * HERE.length)])
/* --- --- --- */
Array.prototype.rand = function(){return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]}
["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].rand()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an IIFE like this:

```js
let r = (e=>e[Math.random()*e.length|0])(["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])

console.log(r)
```

Note that `|0` is equivalent to Math.floor() when the number is less than 2^31

Answer (score -1):

The length of the array can be accessed as a property of the array literal using dot notation:

```
["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].length;
```

Hence you could generate a random element value using the following:

```js
console.log(["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"][Math.floor(["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].length * Math.random())]);
```